# Errror when i try to uppload in DevOps

Tags: file, upload, devops, azure-repos

Could someone help me with this. I'm trying to upload files using Repos and I get this error message

`[error]unauthorized: Invalid client id or client secret.`

`[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1`

How do I solve this?

I have tried to change `Project settings/(code)Repostitories/Git Repositories/Users/Build Service`

`Allow: Contribute to pull requests, Create branch, Create tag, Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags)`